# Jump out of similar lines in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a text file like below, how can I:

```
Warning 1
Warning 2
Error
Warning 3  -> supposed I'm here
Warning 4
Warning 5
...
Warning n  -> how can I get here - the last match of the consecutive matches
Info 
Warning n+1 -> not here
...
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

You can search using a regex negation operator and search offset like this:

```
/\v^(Warning)@!/-1
```

This is `/` to search using `\v` or "very magic" mode (otherwise the `()` and `@` would need to be backslash-escaped). The `^` matches the start of a line and `(...)@!` matches what's *not* in parentheses. The offset of `-1` will go up one line from your match (and the 1 can be omitted, so `-` is also fine). Essentially, you're looking for a line above one not starting with "Warning".

The crucial items are the negation operator( see [`:help /\@!`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21)) and offset (see [`:help search-offset`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#search-offset)).

When browsing the file, you would typically create a search pattern like this

```
0/\v^(<C-R><C-W>)@!/-
```

Where `0` goes to the first character in the line (so the cursor is on "Warning"). Then start editing the search pattern and - after opening the parenthesis - press <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> (see [`:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W)) to put the word under the cursor (still "Warning") into the command line. Finish the search pattern and go.

Note: if there are not too many similar lines, you might actually be much faster by just hitting `*` repeatedly.